# Google Sigin using Firebase not working in Internal Test track

Tags: android, firebase, google-signin

I am using firebase Auth for authentication using google, when installed directly to a emulator or via apk it is working as it should.
But after publishing it in internal test track of google play it does not go past the signin screen,

I have done all the basic things like adding both SHA1 and SHA 256 fingerprints.

Please help

Answer (score 7):

Ok, I found the answer myself, google play console makes a new set of fingerprints which can be found in Release < Setup < App Intergrity, replace these in your firebase project settings and it now works as it should!

Comment: I did the same but it is still not working, do you have any other step that I can be missing?

Comment: @Arpit you also have to add the SHA keys given under the heading **Internal test certificate**.  You can navigate to the above page via - Setup > Internal app sharing menu option in the left side pane

Comment: I did this as well but still not working. Internal is not working bus Closed is working

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to enter the Sha-1 (located in Settings > App Health > App Signatures > App Signing Key Certificate)

Along with the others in your project's firebase configuration, then downloaded GoogleServices.json and generated a new internal test version? It worked here for me, I hope it works

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).